# Find the spectrum of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am trying to learn some basic stuff about spectral theory, and I am a little bit lost. Please, could you help me and tell me how to find  $\sigma(T)$ and $\sigma_p(T)$ of the operator $T:C([0,1]) 
\rightarrow C([0,1])$  $$Tf=f+f(0)-f(1).$$
I have some result where is written that the right answer is  $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T)= \{0\}$ but I do not know how to prove it.

And I also do not understand why $\sigma_p(T)$ does not contain $1$.

Because of $$Tf=f+f(0)-f(1)=\lambda f$$
if $\lambda =1$ we can take in account e.g. constant function, so $Tf=f $.

But from some reason, this is not in my teacher´s results.

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: what do you mean by $\sigma(T)$ and $\sigma_{p}(T)$? Spectrum?

Comment: @Greg $\sigma$ is the spectrum and $\sigma_p$ is the point spectrum

Comment: Perhaps you copied $T$ wrong.  Maybe it should be $Tf = f(0) - f(1)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No I am sure, that the operator looks as I wrote. We have it on our teacher´s webpage and I had checked it many times if I copied it.

Comment: This is definitely something worth asking the teacher about, if you haven't tried already.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok, thank you. And please, do not you know the right answer? I have some idea but I do not know if it is right.

Comment: I don't.  If you have an idea, perhaps you should add it to the body of your question, or as an answer to your own question.  It seems very clear to me that we should have $1 \in \sigma_p(T)$.

Comment: for the definitions of $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma$ [wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Classification_of_points_in_the_spectrum_of_an_operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Classification_of_points_in_the_spectrum_of_an_operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. If $Tf=\lambda f$, we have
$
\lambda f = f + f(1) - f(0),
$
or 
$$\tag{1}
(\lambda - 1) \, f= f(1)-f(0).
$$
If $\lambda=1$, then any $f$ with $f(1)=f(0)$ satisfies the equation, so $1\in\sigma_p(T)$. In particular, as you mention, constant functions are eigenfunctions for the eigenvalue $1$.

When $\lambda\ne1$, the equation $(1)$ has no solution: when $t=1$ and $t=0$, we get respectively
$$
(\lambda-1)f(1)=f(1)-f(0),\ \ \ \ \ (\lambda-1)f(0)=f(1)-f(0),
$$
which imply that $f(1)=f(0)$; but then we go back to $(1)$ and get $f(t)=0$. So $\lambda\ne1$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

Consider the operator $Sf=f+f(0)-f(1)$. Then 
\begin{align}
STf&=S(f+f(1)-f(0))=(f+f(1)-f(0))+(f(0)+f(1)-f(0))-(f(1)+f(1)-f(0))\\ \ \\
&=f+f(1)-f(0)+f(1)-2f(1)+f(0)\\ \ \\
&=f.
\end{align}
And
\begin{align}
TSf&=T(f+f(0)-f(1))=f+f(0)-f(1)+(f(1)+f(0)-f(1))-(f(0)+f(0)-f(1))\\ \ \\
&=f+f(0)-f(1)+f(0)-2f(0)+f(1)\\ \ \\
&=f.
\end{align}
So $T$ is invertible, and $0\not\in\sigma(T)$.

More generally, for $\lambda\ne1$ one can define 
$$
Sf=\frac{f+\alpha f(1)+\beta f(0)}{1-\lambda}
$$
for appropriate $\alpha,\beta$ to get an inverse for $T-\lambda I$.

In summary, $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Glad I could help.